# Pitch recognition to invoke JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-applications, audio

A bit of a vague question but I am working on a project to create a **webapp** which will recognise inaudible (high pitch) sounds from a video playing on a separate device which will then invoke the call of a simple JavaScript function (show/hide, toggle, etc.)

I'm wondering if anyone has had any success with this but using web technologies. This would work only on devices which have microphones obviously, like tablets or phones (or even a desktop with a microphone) but I'm struggling to work out how to get the web app to "hear" the sound. I've found a lot of information about doing this for native iOS apps and also using PhoneGap but I can't find any technology behind doing this with web technologies.

Has anyone succeeded at this?

Comment: I think this should get you going: http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/pitchdetect/index.html from http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/

Comment: the source is http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/pitchdetect/js/pitchdetect.js